# Azure Public facing Loadbalancers

Tags: c#, azure, azure-load-balancer, azure-fluent-api

I want to list all loadbalancers in Azure which have public IP address but I get only a subset and not the entire result.

```
 var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
                                          .FromServicePrincipal(clientId, secret,
                                           tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
                                .Configure()
                               .Authenticate(credentials).WithDefaultSubscription();

foreach (var subscription in azure.Subscriptions.List())
{
      var loadbalancers = azure.LoadBalancers;

      foreach (var loadbalancer in loadbalancers.List())
      {
        if (loadbalancer.PublicFrontends.Count >= 1)
        {
          writelog("load balancer:" + loadbalancer.Name);
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authenticate to each subscription and then get the list of load balancer.